# Magento Customer Group in CMS Pages

Tags: magento, templates, content-management-system, tags

is there a way to expose the customer group id within a CMS page *without* touching any php file? Just like {{var customer.group_id}} in the transactional email templates?

Thanks in advance!

Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

PHP would be required (extension? would still need PHP though).

Comment: Well, actually an extension would be fine.
I would just prefer a solution that exposes several variables to the CMS in a tested way, rather than touching the templates on my own (for single variables..)

Comment: I don't know of an extension that would do that, but my answer is correct.  You cannot do that without PHP.